# React Component Integration into Angular - Handling Dynamic Content Updates from Angular's Change Detection

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

I've been working on a project where I need to integrate a specific React component into an existing Angular application. I've successfully managed to use the React2Angular library to render the component in my Angular app, and it works well for the most part. However, I'm facing a rather tricky issue with handling dynamic content updates.

Here's what I've done so far:

Created a wrapper component in Angular to encapsulate the React component.
Used the react2angular function to convert the React component for use in Angular.
The issue I'm facing is that the React component isn't properly updating when the data passed from the Angular component changes. I understand that Angular has its own change detection mechanism, but I'm struggling to figure out how to trigger updates to the React component based on Angular's change detection.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
// Angular Wrapper Component
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { react2angular } from 'react2angular';
import MyReactComponent from './MyReactComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-react-wrapper',
  template: '<my-react-component [prop1]="prop1" [prop2]="prop2"></my-react-component>',
})
export class ReactWrapperComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() prop1: string;
  @Input() prop2: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // How to update the React component with new prop values?
  }
}

angular
  .module('myApp', ['react'])
  .component('myReactComponent', react2angular(MyReactComponent, ['prop1', 'prop2']));
```

My question is, how can I ensure that the React component updates when the @Input() properties change in the Angular wrapper component? Are there any best practices or specific techniques to make this work seamlessly?

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please clarify what's the `tricky issue` is about? React2Angular should resolve prop updates process. If you change the property on Angular Level, it should be passed to your React component automaticaly. If you would like change something from inside React component, then you should pass the `onChange` property in you wrapper component and using template.